# Hash Table Separate Chaining with Vectors

Tags: c++, function, vector, hashtable, chaining

I'm am currently trying to make a hash table with vectors, and am not sure how to call certain values. We are using type K and V and I'm guessing type V is the value since type K is representing the key most of the time, but I was getting lost figuring out how to do some of the functions below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>

// Custom project includes
#include "Hash.h"

// Namespaces to include
using std::vector;
using std::list;
using std::pair;

//
// Separate chaining based hash table - inherits from Hash
//
template<typename K, typename V>
class ChainingHash : public Hash<K,V> {

    int table_size;

private:
    vector<list<V>> table;          // Vector of Linked lists

public:

    ChainingHash(int n = 11) : table(n){

        //this -> table_size = n;

        //table = new vector<list<K,V>>(n);

    }

    ~ChainingHash() {
        //this->clear();
    }

    bool empty() {
    
        if (!table.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
    
        return true;

    }

    int size() {

        return table.size();

    }

    //Returns the value with key k
    V& at(const K& key) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Key not in hash");
    }

    //Returns the value with key k
    V& operator[](const K& key) {
    } 


    //Returns the number of elements with key k
    int count(const K& key) {

        for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        
        }

    }

    //Adds element with key, true if successful
    void emplace(K key, V value) {
    }

    //Adds pair to hash, true if successful
    void insert(const std::pair<K, V>& pair) {
    }

    //Removes all any (if any) entries with key k
    void erase(const K& key) {
    }

    //Empties the hash
    void clear() {

        for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        
    }

}
```

I don't need help on all the function, but I would like to understand the gist of using the key and values in order to find which bucket they belong in. I am mostly just unsure of what the value (number) that is inputted, what label we are supposed to give that in relation to the rest of the code. Also if you see any mistakes in my code so far, feel free to mention that! Thanks so much!

I am also struggling with the function int count, just on the part when you find the bucket with the same key, how you would go about searching the linked list, I am not sure if it's just item->next or if it's called something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hash the key using a hash function (which I guess is provided by `Hash.h` in the code) and then find the *bucket* (vector's index in this case) to insert the *key* in. If multiple keys hash to the same bucket, you need to just add the keys to the list. Use `list::insert()` for inserting([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)).

To retrieve the value associated with the key, you'll actually need to store a `pair` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)) of the `<Key,Value>` in the list so that on iterating over the list of keys that collided and were added to the same bucket, the value can be retrieved.

For searching the linked list, just traverse it in the regular `for(a:x)` fashion

```
list = table[idx]; //idx found after hashing the key
int count = 0;
for(const auto& elem: list) {
    if(elem.first == key) {
       count++;
    }
}
return count;
```